# Recursively loop through directory and collect all xml files

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to loop through a given directory path and resursively collect all xml files. However, for some reason my results are only returning part of the filepaths not all of them. I'm not sure where im going wrong with this.

If you guys suggest i do not use qtiterator and use some other method that is fine as well.

[image]

```
QList<QDomNode> collect_library_nodes (const QString &path) {

    // collect all xml files
    QDir dir(path);
    dir.setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    dir.setNameFilters(QStringList("*.xml"));

    QList<QString> filepaths;
    QDirIterator it(dir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        qDebug() << "FILE" << it.next();
        filepaths.append(it.next());
    }

    qDebug() << 'COUNT:' << filepaths.count();

    // collect xml nodes
    QList<QDomNode> library_nodes;

    return library_nodes;
}
```

When i run the program i get a file count of 15 instead of what should be 27 since there are xml files in subfolders.

Here is the current output:

```
Debugging starts
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/a.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/c.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/e.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_a"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_b"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_c"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_d"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_e"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_e/r.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_f/s.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_g"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_g/v.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_g/x.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/h.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/j.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/l.xml"
COUNT: 16
```

it should be outputting:

```
Debugging starts
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/a.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/b.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/c.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/d.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/e.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/f.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/g.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/h.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/i.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/j.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/k.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/l.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_a/m.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_b/n.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_c/o.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_d/p.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_e/q.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_e/r.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_f/s.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_f/t.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_g/u.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_g/v.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_g/w.xml"
FILE: "C:/Users/Martini/Desktop/trash/master/folder_g/x.xml"
COUNT: 24
```

Comment: What output did you expect from your program? What output do you actually get?

Comment: More specifically, what are some examples of files that weren't returned?

Comment: I updated the question to give me specifics about the issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `it.next()` twice in your loop. Thus you skip each second file. In other words you output each file path on odd position and collect each file path on even position.

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << "FILE" << it.next();
    filepaths.append(it.next());
}
```

Should be something like below:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    const auto& fn = it.next();
    qDebug() << "FILE" << fn;
    filepaths.append(fn);
}
```

Or:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << "FILE" << it.next();
    filepaths.append(it.filePath());
}
```

Comment: I noticed it returns folder paths, how can i edit it to only return file paths to xml files?

Comment: It is another question. Please ask new one.

Comment: haha of gosh, please spare me. The original question is collecting xml files. I'm not making an entirely new question for that. I'll figure it it, just forget it.